# Metallic Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have recently heard about the existence of the so called *metallic Riemannian manifolds*. As far as I understand, those are manifold with a polynomial structure, compatible with the Riemannian metric, induced by a $(1,1)$ tensor $J$ satisfying a metallic equation
$$
J^2 = pJ + qI
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers and $I$ is the identity operator.

Why are they studied? Is there any geometric application? I mean, does the existence of a metallic structure imply some interesting geometric or topological property of the manifold?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of them.

I don't think there are constraints for a metric to be metallic. Suppose $M,g$ is a Riemannian manifold and chose $p,q$ positive and integer. Let $\lambda_{\pm}=\frac{p\pm\sqrt{p^2+4q}}{2}$. Consider $J=\lambda_{\pm} I$. Then $J^2=pJ+qI$ and I believe $(M,g,J)$ is metallic.

Comment: Right. But then what is the point of introducing this extra structure?

Comment: I don't know. I guess the papers ought to discuss this no?